# How to get a column value from a HTML table using django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I have a HTML table with checkboxes. I want to read the first column value based on the row selected using the checkbox. To read the values, a function is called after selecting the checkbox and clicking a button.

[Table look this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suXK0.png)

```
<a href="{% url 'app-analyze_retina' %}">
    <button onclick="" class="patient-add-btn button1"> Send for Analysis </button>
    </a>
    {% if btn_clicked %}

        <div>
            <table class="table" id="patient_list">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Patient ID</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Result/Severity Level</th>
              <th scope="col">Tested on</th>
              <th scope="col">AI confidence</th>
              <th scope="col">Comments</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for patient in data %}
                 <tr>
                <td bgcolor="mediumaquagreen">

                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="checks" id={{patient.0}} value="{{patient.1}}">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for={{patient.0}}>{{patient.1}}</label>
                  </div>
<!--                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen" > {{ patient.1 }}</td>-->
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen">{{patient.2}}</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen" >{{patient.3}}</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen">2.846</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen">-</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen" >Cristina</td>
                    <td  bgcolor="mediumaquagreen" >913</td>
                  </td>

              </tr>
             {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>

    {% endif %}
```

## Function to read the values

```
 def analyze_img(request):
        c = request.POST.getlist('checks')
        print(c)
        return render(request, 'workspace.html')
```

First I was trying to check whether I am able to read a checkbox but it returns an empty list.

Comment: Where do you *submit* the form? You only create a button as far as I can see, hence it will, given you implement this, visit the link, that's it. You need to sumbit a form.

Comment: should i add the type of the button as "submit" to get the values into my function? I didn't use the form, I just created a table. Is this the wrong way.

Comment: did you define a `<form>` that wraps the checkboxes?

Comment: No. its without <form>.